# unix - remove (i) empty space between single characters and (ii) more than X consecutive instances of a word

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I would like to

(i) replace blank space between characters only if these characters are *single*; i.e. for instance

```
Down [Enter] p s -- a u x [Delete]
```

should become

```
Down [Enter] ps -- aux [Delete]
```

(ii) remove words that are consecutively repeated more than X times until any other thing which is not the word, so that (say X=2)

```
 [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] ab inition [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] [Delete] ab definitio
```

becomes

```
 [Delete] [Delete] ab initio [Delete] [Delete] ab definitio
```

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You did not get a lot of responses. I think the main reason is the combination of two different questions, both non-trivial. Normally it helps to show your own effort, but I anderstand your effort might have been thinkong for hours "where to start".

The first question, removing spaces between single characters, can be done with a loop in `sed`:

```
echo 'Down [Enter] p s -- a u x [Delete] ' | 
   sed -r ':a;s/( [^ ]|\r) ([^ ])( |$)/\1\2\r\3/;ta; s/\r//g'
Down [Enter] ps -- aux [Delete]
```

Explanation:
With a direct approach `a u x` will be changed into `au x` after the first replace, and the other space will be forgotten. You need to go over the replacements more than once and remember that the letter `u` in `au x` was a singleton in the original string.
For remembering the places where a replacement has been done, we use a `\r` (and remove it later).

`:a;` Label to return for the next replacement.
`( [^ ]|\r)` A space followed by a letter OR our temporary `\r` marker
`([^ ])` A space followed by a letter
`( |$)` A space or end-of-line
`/\1\2\r\3/` Replace with the two remembered characters, insert a special marker and a space when it was not the last charater of the line.
`ta` Go back to the start-of-loop tag `:a` when something was replaced
`s/\r//g'` Remove our temporary markers.

The second question is difficult too. The next solution is close but incorrect:

```
for (( X=2; X<8; X++)); do
  echo "X=$X (incorrect solution)"
  echo 'some some some some some some some some some some some input' |
     sed -r 's/([^ ]+[ ]+)(\1{'${X}'})(\1+)/\2/g'
done
```

The problem is when the repeated string also appears on another place, as in
`some some some input some some some` or worse `some some some input input input`.

I do not see an easy fix for the `sed` solution, but `awk` will help here.
For counting repeated fields my solution is considering each word as one record.

```
for (( X=2; X<8; X++)); do
   echo "X=$X"
   echo 'some some some some some some some some some some some input some some some some' |
      awk -v x=$X 'BEGIN {RS="[ \n]"; ORS='\n'; repeated=1}
         { if (last==$0)
             repeated++;
           else
             repeated=1;
         }
         {last=$0}
         repeated <= x {print $0" "}
         END {print "\n"}
      '
done
```

Comment: Dear Walter. You are absolutely right, my apologies. It is my first post here. The solution I had come up with involves python, while I would prefer to stick to usual unix tools. I was looking into tr but I did not see a way.  Thanks for your reply. There's a problem with (i), because your solution is removing all 'r' from the file, at least with my sed (I'm using OpenBSD here, not linux). As for (ii), I will try it now.

Comment: (i) In my `sed` the carriage return `\r` works. It should be an unique character, perhaps `Q` for a test. Try replacing the \r with control-v control-m.